# Explanation required - 3-D Arrays, Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I came across this snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2][2][2] = { {10,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8} };
    int *p,*q;
    p=&a[2][2][2];
    *q=***a;
    printf("%d----%d",*p,*q);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:** Garbage Value ---- 1

**This was the explanation:**

```
p=&a[2][2][2] you declare only two 2D arrays, but you are trying to access
the third 2D(which you are not declared) it will print garbage values. *q=***a starting address of a is assigned integer pointer. Now q is pointing to starting address of a. If you print *q, it will print first element of 3D array.
```

**However, I am still unable to understand the same. I would like the same to be provided in an easy to understand manner (Not that I am complaining about the above explanation).**

**Explanation** on the 6th and 7th line may please be provided.

Comment: `q` is not initialized, so dereferencing it with `*q` is undefined behavior.

Comment: "I came across this snippet" Will you provide a source or at least the complete context for this code in your question?

Comment: It s a standard problem of either finding the errors in the snippet or predicting the output as I had previously mentioned.

Comment: Please provide the *exact* wording of the problem from the textbook so that we can help you. By paraphrasing, you risk leaving out important information that will lead to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[2][2][2] = { {10,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8} };
```

`a` is declared as a 3D array, but you initialize it with a 2D array.

```
    int *p,*q;
    p=&a[2][2][2];
```

`p` is initialized to an invalid memory location. Since `a` has only 2 elements per dimension, the only valid subscripts are `0` and `1`.

```
    *q=***a;
```

`q` has not been initialized to point to a valid location in memory. Derferencing `q` with `*q` is undefined behavior.

```
    printf("%d----%d",*p,*q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will go through this. Not 'my code', I pulled down something for practice.

Comment: Would you mind providing corrective action for each of the above errors, so that I can correlate.

Comment: @Masse I suggest that you find "practice code" somewhere else. If this is a typical example from your current source, then throw it away.

Comment: @Masse As I wrote this answer, I tried to think of any positive suggestions that I can make. However, the purpose of the code is unclear, so I wasn't able to come up with any.

Comment: Thanks. These are "Predict the output / Find the errors" type questions. I did not take the 'errors' too seriously. I have to know them first before I really 'judge' them.

Comment: True, may be an example to print a valid array element by using the above technique could assist me even more.

Comment: @Masse It might help if you edit your question to provide some context. For example, if this code comes from an exercise problem, you should include the instructions given in the exercise.